# Angular need to load modules with a preceeding slash

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

When the top javascript files are automatically loading into the view it needs a slash in front of it so it doesn't try to load every JS file from /foo/response.js instead of /response.js.

I have tried adding "baseUrl": "/", however that doesn't build. It only works if I use "./"

Also in index I manually am adding env.js which is why that one has a slash. The rest need slashes in-front.

Finally the reason the page has to load each time is because there are two versions of the website and I'm choosing to load in which template dynamically.

[image]

Comment: You can add it to your angular.json there is a  "scripts" key. Or if you want you can use scriptLoader which add scripts to the DOM.

Comment: I'm using the scripts in angular.json but the path there isn't exactly what gets loaded here. For example one of them is scripts.js but in my angulara.json I have "src/assets/js/scripts.js" but it comes in as "scripts.js" instead of "/scripts.js"